# Formula.Firewall: Query 'Sentiment Results' (step 'Custom1') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source

Tags: powerbi, sentiment-analysis

I want to learn sentiment analysis and am learning from this tutorial https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Sentiment-Analysis-in-Power-BI/ba-p/55898, but I got an error:

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'Sentiment Results' (step 'Custom1') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

I tried to change Data source setting > Edit privacy level, but that did not work.

Answer (score 4):

To solve the issue you must do **Fast Combine Setting**, **found in File > Options and settings > Options** and then Current File > Privacy determines whether Power BI Desktop uses your Privacy Level settings while combining data. 
Reference : 
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-privacy-levels/

Comment: This does not resolve the issue for me. Likely if users are encountering this error, they will need to load their queries into staging queries before trying to merge them. More info at https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/03/11/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/